# When the only relevant part of a code-only answer is a poor clone of the accepted answer

Tags: discussion, answers, flags

I've a few issues with this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5064617

- The only line of it that is relevant to the question ("How do I get the user's desktop folder?") is the first line, and it's essentially identical to the accepted answer, but with a poorer choice of variable name ("filepath") because the method call results in a path to a folder, not a file
- The other lines are generally fairly low quality or ill thought out from a coding perspective - the question doesn't ask about folder creation, nor path generation
- The code lines use string concat to build a path to a directory called `.log` and then it's created after a useless call to check if it exists
- Zero words of explanation as to why any of this is done, how it relates to the question or provide any indication as to why it's a better answer than the massively upvoted, accepted answer
- It feels like it was copypasted without much thought or tailoring, from a codebase that seeks to create a folder called `.log` and then perhaps put all the `*.log` files in it.. Or it had a few variables/lines chopped out to the point where it no longer really makes sense

I don't know if there is a relevant course of action in "Flag"; the closest is "Flag for mod attention" button, because it's basically a low quality/noisy repetition of the accepted answer on what would appear to be a fairly good question/answer for a web search like "get user desktop folder c#", but while a moderator may get involved with an answer on ground 1 (duplicates another answer) they aren't supposed to be SME enough to judge the other points, unless "obviously answers a question that was not asked/is not an answer to the question asked" ? (And they probably also have more pressing issues to attend to)